# Get a record outside of an `Include'`

Tags: haskell, ihp

I have a post that has an `Include'` as I've `fetch`ed it with a `fetchRelated`, so it has this type:

`post :: Include' ["comments"] Post`

If I'd like to save it, I'd get an error

```hs
post 
  |> set #title "Foo"
  |> updateRecord
```

The compiler will complain it's not a `Post`. It's an `Include ... Post`

My question is - can the `Post` be extracted out of the include, so I won't have to fetch it again from the DB?

Answer (score 4):

There's no built-in function in IHP to do this. But you can use a custom helper like this:

```hs
clearComments :: Include "comments" Post -> Post
clearComments post = updateField @"comments" (newRecord @Post).comments post
```

And then use it like this:

```hs
post 
  |> set #title "Foo"
  |> clearComments
  |> updateRecord
```

Things can get slightly more complex when we have multiple Include. The compiler will error out,

```hs
clearIncludes :: Include ["comments", "tags"] Post -> Post
clearIncludes post = post
              |> updateField @"comments" (newRecord @Post).comments
              |> updateField @"tags" (newRecord @Post).tags
```

We need to split this into multiple functions, each with types annotations:

```hs
clear1 :: Include' ["comments", "tags"] Post -> Include "tags" Post
clear1 post = post
       |> updateField @"comments" (newRecord @Post).comments


clear2 :: Include "tags" Post -> Post
clear2 post = post
       |> updateField @"tags" (newRecord @Post).tags
```

March has explained the reason:

TL;DR: `updateField` has a more open type signature than `set` and sometimes GHC needs a bit of help

In very early IHP versions `updateField` was actually `set` and it was later changed (because it was causing errors like these). The core problem with `updateField` is, that it's type definition is very open. It's defined as [`updateField :: value' -> model -> model'`](https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/blob/master/IHP/HaskellSupport.hs#LL246C5-L246C45). Here `model` and `model'` are two independent type variables. This means a call to `updateField` can actually change the return type of the record (e.g. turning `Post` to `Post "tags" LandingPage`). The problem with your first version was that GHC could not figure out the `model'` variable because multiple `updateField` were chained (the `model` type argument is easy for GHC to figure out, it's just that the `model'` is independent of that).

For comparison `set` is defined as `set :: value -> model -> model`. In that case when GHC can figure out `model` it will never error. So `set` is typically easy to figure out and unlikely to error. One the other side the problem with `set` is that it's less flexible and cannot change the output type (e.g. with `model = Post` it will be `set :: value -> Post -> Post`, so there's no way to express e.g. the `Include` stuff). That's why `updateField` exists.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to have a little fun and see if I could generalize Marc's answer above. Here's what I came up with! This is for a single include:

```hs
clearInclude :: forall model field fieldValue. (
        UpdateField field (Include field model) model fieldValue fieldValue,
        HasField field model fieldValue,
        Record model
    ) => Include field model -> model
clearInclude model = 
    model 
        |> updateField @field (getField @field (newRecord @model))
```

This should work with any datatype with a single `Include`d data type. Then I tried it with two and three, which is pretty easy:

```hs
clearInclude2 :: _ => Include field1 (Include field2 model) -> model
clearInclude2 model =
    model 
        |> clearInclude
        |> clearInclude

clearInclude3 :: _ => Include field1 (Include field2 (Include field3 model)) -> model
clearInclude3 model =
    model 
        |> clearInclude
        |> clearInclude
        |> clearInclude
```

I still haven't figured out how to get it to compile when I fill out the typeclass constraints fully, and I still need to figure out how to make it work with the `Include'` compact notation, but this was a fun problem to get started on, and maybe we can continue to generalize further :)

Comment: I've pretty much stopped using includes. I'm using this approach instead, which is more easily extendible and "future ready"  - 
https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/blob/45902cce813a378f413f05628defec2e1e493a7d/Guide/relationships.markdown?plain=1#L340-L450

Comment: Yes, in that case this works perfectly well :)